# VS Code no longer recognising html files

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

For some reason when I try to create an html file vs code doesn't seem to recognize it and nothing html related works within it (autocomplete, etc). I'm not really sure where to go from here since VS code has been my go-to work environment.
Here's a picture of what it's saving the file as (usually the logo beside the file would look like this: <> ):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just save it as html.

otherwise in the bottom right there is an option to change the language
[image: vs code language selector]

Comment: no worries, if this solves your problem please mark this answer